# How can I prevent my array from being overwritten when setting the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I am trying to do**: I want to add all elements into my array

**Actual result**: My array is being overwritten

As seen from my codesandbox, the output should be `helloworld`, but it is only showing `world`.

Parent.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child setArr={setArr} />
      {arr}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setArr("hello");
    props.setArr("world");
  });
  return (
    <div className="Child">
      <h1>This is child componemnt</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-overrite-array-vuyoz?file=/src/Parent.js)

Comment: Please share code with the question

Comment: try   accessing old state and add data useEffect(() => {
    props.setArr((state) => [...state, "Hello"]);
    props.setArr((state) => [...state, "world"]);
    }, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwriting your array with a string, the trick is to create a shallow copy of your value and mutate the new copy. and then set the state afterwards:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child setArr={setArr} arr={arr} />
      {arr}
    </div>
  );
}

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const nextArr = [...props.arr];
    nextArr.push("hello", "world");
    props.setArr(nextArr);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="Child">
      <h1>This is child componemnt</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this helps thanks !!